# SQL getting the maximum value of the average of the values

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-order-by, inner-join, average

So, I have a database of a school. It has a students table and a grades table.
I want to do a query, that will give me the student with the highest average, how can I do it?
I don't get it how I should get the maximum value from the average values.. any help?

EDIT: For the guy who's trying to help me, this is the error I'm getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQHX4.png)

and this is the code:

```
SELECT TOP (1) studentsTbl.studentId, studentsTbl.name, Avg(gradesTbl.grade)
FROM studentsTbl INNER JOIN gradesTbl ON studentsTbl.studentId = gradesTbl.studentId
GROUP BY studentsTbl.studentId, studentsTbl.name
ORDER BY Avg(gradesTbl.grade) DESC;
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using . . . and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Don't do it all at once. Do it in two steps. First make a query to give one row per student, including their average mark. Then, use that as a Sub-Query, and select the first row when ordered by the average mark descending.

Answer (score 0):

That's aggregation and a row-limiting clause. Assuming a table like `marks(student_id, mark)`, you would do:

```
select student_id, avg(mark) avg_mark
from marks
group by student_id
order by avg_mark desc limit 1
```

The syntax for the row-limiting clause might vary across databases. `limit` is not supported in all databases, but the all have an equivalent syntax.

If you have the students in another table, say `students(student_id, name)`, you can `join` it:

```
select s.student_id, s.name, avg(m.mark) avg_mark
from students s 
inner join marks m on m.student_id = s.student_id
group by s.student_id, s.name
order by avg_mark desc limit 1
```

In MS Access, use `top`:

```
select top 1 s.student_id, s.name, avg(m.mark) as avg_mark
from students as s 
inner join marks as m on m.student_id = s.student_id
group by s.student_id, s.name
order by avg_mark desc
```

Comment: It says for me that there's a problem with the LIMIT, does the LIMIT even supported in MS Access?

Comment: @ofekAgayev: if you are running Access, you need `top`. See my update.

Comment: I'm trying to use this, but it doesn't seems to work, it just gives me an error..

Comment: I edited the post so you can see my code and the error

Comment: @ofekAgayev: does it work if you use `seect top 1` instead of `select top (1)`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got this right now. I just selected the name where the student id equals
to the top 1 id where the avg is the bigger.

```
Here is what I did:
SELECT studentsTbl.name
FROM studentsTbl
WHERE studentId = (SELECT TOP 1 studentId FROM gradesTbl GROUP BY studentId ORDER BY AVG(grade) DESC);
```